# Injective hull of quotient of modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring. If $N\leq M$ are $R$-modules, then is $E(M)$ isomorphic to a submodule of $E(N)\oplus E(M/N)$?

Here $E(M)$ denotes the [injective hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull) of $M$.

Comment: What is $R$? Commutative? noetherian?

Comment: For $N=M$, $E(N)\otimes E(M/N)=0$. So this won't be true in general.

Comment: Sorry, is direct sum instead tensor product and R is noetherian and commutative

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true for any ring (no commutativity or noetherianess required).

**Proof:** Suppose we have an embedding $\phi: M \hookrightarrow E(N) \oplus E(M/N)$. Then, since  $E(N) \oplus E(M/N)$ is injective, by the universal property of the injective hull, there is an embedding $E(M) \hookrightarrow E(N) \oplus E(M/N)$ as stated.

Hence it suffices to construct $\phi$: Label the maps as 
$$ 0 \to N \xrightarrow{i}M \xrightarrow{p} M/N \to 0$$
and let $$f: N \hookrightarrow E(N),\qquad g: M/N \hookrightarrow E(M/N)$$ 
be embeddings. By the universal property of injectives (draw a triangle), there is a homomorphismus $h: M \to E(N)$ such that $h \circ i = f$. Define 
$$\phi: M \to E(N) \oplus E(M/N), m \mapsto (h(m), (g\circ p)(m))$$
Now a simple computation shows that $\phi$ is injective. q.e.d.

**Remark:** In disguise this is just an application of the horse lemma for injectives (the construction of $\phi$ is the crucial step in the proof of the horse lemma): See the first version of my answer.

Comment: thanks for clarification